# HTML: can a column span across both header and body rows?

Tags: html, html-table

I've got a table set up like this:

[image]

The first row is a header row, so it's inserted into the `<thead>` region of the HTML. The other rows are body rows, so they go into the `<tbody>` region.

Cell 1:1 has `<td rowspan="4">`

```html
<table>
 <thead>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="4" >
  <p class="body" >Spanned column</p>
  </td>
  <td >
  <p class="body" >Header cell</p>
  </td>
  <td>
  <p class="body" >Header cell</p>
  </td>
  <td>
  <p class="body" >Header cell</p>
  </td>
 </tr></thead>
 <tbody>
 
 <tr>
  <td >
  <p class="body" >Body</p>
  </td>
  <td >
  <p class="body" >Body</p>
  </td>
  <td >
  <p class="body" >Body</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td >
  <p class="body" >Body</p>
  </td>
  <td >
  <p class="body" >Body</p>
  </td>
  <td >
  <p class="body" >Body</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td >
  <p class="body" >Body</p>
  </td>
  <td >
  <p class="body" >Body</p>
  </td>
  <td >
  <p class="body" >Body</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

My editing application allows me to create a column span that contains both heading and body rows, but the export to HTML does not look like the image above: in Antennahouse, the spanned column is treated as not spanned so its contents are placed in cell 1:1, which leaves the body cells shifted one column to the left.

[image]

Firefox also makes a mess.

Is this construction, i.e. a cell that is part of `<thead>` extending into rows that are part of `<tbody>`, legal? I can't find anything in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/tabular-data.html#the-col-element).

Comment: `<td>` has an attribute `rowspan` and that is what you need: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/tabular-data.html#the-td-element

Comment: I was unclear: I'm already using rowspan, it's just not giving the result I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/tabular-data.html#table-model) after all:

> A cell cannot cover slots that are from two or more row groups.

So the construction made by my export is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

See the following example, all you need to know is how many rows there are in the table and use the `rowspan` attribute in the header row.

```css
/*Just some css to make the result more pretty*/
th {
    background-color:#AAA;
}
.white{
    background-color:#FFF;
}

td,th{
   padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan=7 class="white">This is a big row span</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This would mean removing the <thead> and <tbody> regions from the table, in paged media that removes the ability to repeat the header row on a second page.

Comment: @Hobbes that is true, it is not possible to span outside the group.